# Find winner for a game

Tags: java, algorithm

> John and Doe are playing a game. In the game, they are given N keys, where N-1 keys are brass coated and one is silver plated. P is the position of the silver-plated key which is the correct key.
>
> To play, John and Doe take turns and in each turn, they have to choose consecutive M keys which should include the silver key, and reverse their order. To win the game, one has to put the silver-plated key in position X. John starts the game.
>
> Assume John and Doe play optimally.
>
> Note: Indexing is 1-based.
>
> Print the name of the player who wins. Print Draw if the game ends in a draw.
>
> ```
> N = number of keys
> P = position of the silver-plated key
> M = Consecutive keys to be reversed
> X = Winning position
> ```
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> ```
> each input range is from 1 to 10^6
> ```
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> N=3,P=1,M=2,X=2
> ```
>
> **Answer:**
>
> ```
> John
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> There are 3 keys in total. The first one is a silver-plated key. On each turn, players must choose two consecutive keys and reverse their order. The winning position is 2. John starts the game. So he can just choose the first 2 keys and reverse their order. In this turn, he will be able to put a silver key on the winning position. So the answer is John
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> N=4,P=1,M=2,X=4
> ```
>
> **Answer:**
>
> ```
> Draw
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> - There are 4 keys in total. The first one is a silver-plated key. On each turn, players must choose two consecutive keys and reverse their order. The winning position is 4.
> - John starts the game. So he can just choose the first 2 keys and reverse their order. The silver-plated key is at position 2.
> - After that Doe will choose the first 2 keys again reverse them back to put the silver-plated key at position 1. On the other hand, he could have reversed the order of the 2nd and 3rd keys, but on his next turn, John would be able to put the silver-plated key from position 3 to position 4 and win the game.
> - The previous two moves are played infinitely in an optimal game so neither John nor Doe will be able to win the game. So print Draw.

This is my code:

```
public String solve(int N, int P, int M, int X) {
    int[] ar = new int[N];
    ar[P-1] = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<M/2; i++) {
        int x = ar[i], y = ar[M-i-1];
        ar[i] = y;
        ar[M-i-1] = x;
    }
    if(ar[X-1] == 1) return "John";
    for(int i=M; i<(M+M)/2 && i<N; i++) {
        int x = ar[i], y = ar[M+M-i-1];
        ar[i] = y;
        ar[M+M-i-1] = x;
    }
    if(ar[X-1] == 1) return "Doe";
    return "Draw";
}
```

This was asked in Hackerrank some days back in an interview, when I tried my code, 4 test cases were failing which are hidden so I don't have information about those test cases.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: According to your code, Doe never wins. This is definitely wrong. Consider `N=3,P=1,M=2,X=3`.

Comment: I feel like unless John can win or can make a move that doesn't lose him the game after his first turn, the game will always end in a draw. In the case where he wants to make an optimal move to get him closer to winning, Doe can just reverse the move (since both are forced to pick exactly `M` consecutive keys) and prevent himself from possibly losing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the right conclusion that if neither player can win on their first move, it is a draw.

However, your code assumes that the first player will reverse the *first*  keys, and the second player will reverse the second batch of  keys. This we cannot assume. Both players have other possibilities.

Secondly, it really is not necessary to reverse the keys that are not silver plated: it makes no difference. You could do this without any array, and just update the value of .

With brute force, you would play all possible moves of the first player, and check if any of them is a win. If so, we have the answer.

If not, for each state after a first player move, play all possible second player moves. If for all moves of the first player there is a counter move that wins, we have the answer.

If there are no such situations, it is a draw.

This is not difficult to implement, but takes quadratic time in terms of .

We can use arithmetic for this. For instance, the parity is important: if  is odd, then the silver key can only move with even steps, so that if the distance to the target  is odd, there is no chance to ever reach it. We can also check the distance between  and  and if it cannot be bridged with two moves -- i.e. that distance is greater than 2(−1) -- then we can also say it is a draw. And so there are many constraints we can involve to finally arrive at a constant time algorithm:

```
    public static int solve(int N, int P, int M, int X) {
        if (P > X) { // Make sure P < X: so mirror the setup:
            return solve(N, N + 1 - P, M, N + 1 - X);
        }
        int dist = X - P;
        if (dist < M && M % 2 != dist % 2 && P + X > M && 2*N + 2 > M + P + X) {
            return 1; // First player wins
        }
        if (dist % 2 == 1 || P + X > 2*M || P + X > 2*(N + 1 - M)) {
            return 0; // Draw
        }
        return 2; // Second player wins
    }
```